# Extract a part of a string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string below

```
<input type="text" name="__test" value="gvhchycvcghcgcgc">
```

how to get he value part in php from the above string.

Answer (score 0):

What issue do you face here? I've written a sample code like you and it works completely fine by simply using $_POST.

**x.php**

```
<form method="post" action="t.php">
    <input type="text" name="__somename" value="asa">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**t.php**

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_POST["__somename"]);
```

**Output**

array (size=1)
  '__somename' => string 'asa' (length=3)

string 'asa' (length=3)